# Why is my grok filter not parsing my filebeats messages ? I cannot see the logstash parsed field in Kibana (ELK)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have `Filesbeat` configured and it is able to read new log (`syslog` for now) from the path provided in the `filebeat.yml` file and forward it to `Logstash` which should then parse the data forward that to `Elasticearch`.

I do not see the parsed grok fields such as syslog_timestamp, syslog_hostname, syslog_pid anywhere in the Kibana event and i dont know what could be the reason as to why the data is not parsed.

**Filebeat input file**

[image]

**Grok Filter (in Logstash)**

```
input{
        beats{
                port => "5044"
        }
}

filter {
        if[type] == "syslog"{
                grok{
                        match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"}
                }
                date {
                        match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
                }
        }
}

output{
        elasticsearch{
                hosts => ["10.107.50.205:9200"]
                index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```

**Kibana (Elasticsearch Json)**

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-2019.09.30",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "kss7g20B5aLjyCF-6L2B",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Sep 30 18:33:20 ut012905 metricbeat[46882]: 2019-09-30T18:33:20.254+0100#011INFO#011[monitoring]#011log/log.go:145#011Non-zero metrics in the last 30s#011{\"monitoring\": {\"metrics\": {\"beat\":{\"cpu\":{\"system\":{\"ticks\":770020,\"time\":{\"ms\":80}},\"total\":{\"ticks\":2091400,\"time\":{\"ms\":172},\"value\":2091400},\"user\":{\"ticks\":1321380,\"time\":{\"ms\":92}}},\"handles\":{\"limit\":{\"hard\":4096,\"soft\":1024},\"open\":5},\"info\":{\"ephemeral_id\":\"63755af9-7bad-4b09-8909-52e7018409fe\",\"uptime\":{\"ms\":369450706}},\"memstats\":{\"gc_next\":23786560,\"memory_alloc\":12161776,\"memory_total\":453661591544,\"rss\":2052096},\"runtime\":{\"goroutines\":36}},\"libbeat\":{\"config\":{\"module\":{\"running\":0}},\"pipeline\":{\"clients\":3,\"events\":{\"active\":89,\"published\":47,\"total\":47}}},\"metricbeat\":{\"system\":{\"cpu\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3},\"filesystem\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3},\"fsstat\":{\"events\":1,\"success\":1},\"load\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3},\"memory\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3},\"network\":{\"events\":6,\"success\":6},\"process\":{\"events\":22,\"success\":22},\"process_summary\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3},\"socket_summary\":{\"events\":3,\"success\":3}}},\"system\":{\"load\":{\"1\":0.04,\"15\":0.01,\"5\":0.04,\"norm\":{\"1\":0.04,\"15\":0.01,\"5\":0.04}}}}}}",
    "host": {
      "containerized": false,
      "name": "ut012905",
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "hostname": "ut012905",
      "id": "74e969e835cbfe982aa3ed2f5d76fdd9",
      "os": {
        "platform": "ubuntu",
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "version": "16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)",
        "codename": "xenial",
        "family": "debian",
        "kernel": "4.4.0-161-generic"
      }
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "agent": {
      "id": "afafb888-8d08-4a4b-8f4d-6c64291fb43d",
      "version": "7.3.2",
      "hostname": "ut012905",
      "type": "filebeat",
      "ephemeral_id": "57c8f630-00d5-4c88-bf2d-bb1102cd8530"
    },
    "log": {
      "offset": 3218320,
      "file": {
        "path": "/var/log/syslog"
      }
    },
    "tags": [
      "myCluster1",
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "fields": {
      "env": "staging"
    },
    "@timestamp": "2019-09-30T17:33:23.354Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-09-30T17:33:23.354Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1569864803354
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document_type` setting was removed from Filebeat on version 6.0, since you are using Filebeat 7.3 this setting is ignored and your message does not have the `type` field.

You need to use [`fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.0/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) to add a new field and change your pipeline to filter based on that field.

You need something like this in your filebeat configuration.

```
fields:
  type: syslog
```

Then you need to change your conditional in Logstash.

```
if [fields][type] == "syslog"
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought that was the reason too after posting the question. It worked, thanks again!